# F# iteration over a Dictionary

Tags: f#

I'm just starting with F# and I want to iterate over a dictionary, getting the keys and values.

So in C#, I'd put:

```
IDictionary resultSet = test.GetResults;
foreach (DictionaryEntry de in resultSet)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Key = {0}, Value = {1}", de.Key, de.Value);
}
```

I can't seem to find a way to do this in F# (not one that compiles anyway).

Could anybody please suggest the equivalent code in F#?

Cheers,

Crush

Answer (score 22):

What is the type of your dictionary?

If it is non-generic `IDictionary` as your code snippet suggests, then try the following (In F#, `for` doesn't implicitly insert conversions, so you need to add `Seq.cast<>` to get a typed collection that you can easily work with):

```
for entry in dict |> Seq.cast<DictionaryEntry> do
  // use 'entry.Value' and 'entry.Key' here
```

If you are using generic `IDictionary<'K, 'V>` then you don't need the call to `Seq.cast` (if you have any control over the library, this is better than the previous option):

```
for entry in dict do
  // use 'entry.Value' and 'entry.Key' here
```

If you're using immutable F# `Map<'K, 'V>` type (which is the best type to use if you're writing functional code in F#) then you can use the solution by Pavel or you can use `for` loop together with the `KeyValue` active pattern like this:

```
for KeyValue(k, v) in dict do
  // 'k' is the key, 'v' is the value
```

In both of the cases, you can use either `for` or various `iter` functions. If you need to perform something with side-effects then I would prefer `for` loop (and this is not the first answer where I am mentioning this :-)), because this is a language construct designed for this purpose. For functional processing you can use various functions like `Seq.filter` etc..

Comment: Good call with the loop for methods *(function?)* with side-effects.

Comment: But the whole point of `iter` is to perform side effects as well (as evidenced by its type), so it's also "designed for this purpose"... (which isn't to say that `for` is inferior, of course; in fact, I just didn't know about `KeyValue`).

Comment: @Pavel: Yes, `iter` is also designed for this purpose. However, my impression is that `iter` is inherited from OCaml and the F# way of doing this is to use `for` (this is probably a personal preference though). Generally, I think that language constructs are preferrable over library functions if you're doing something where the language construct is suitable.

Comment: `iter` has the advantage of meshing well with the pipeline syntax when you're doing a bunch of other things (e.g. `filter` or `map`) - it is clearly visible as the final step in the pipeline, whereas with `for` it stands out from the rest of it. For another thing, it is curryable. So I don't think it's just a legacy thing (ultimately, if it was just that, it wouldn't be in `Seq`). Then there are `iteri`, `iter2` and friends which do have some extra functionality not present in `for` (unless you do `zip` and `mapi` first) - and once you start using them, plain `iter` is kinda more consistent.

Comment: @Pavel: The point about working well with the pipeline is a good one. I also use `iter` in this case (and `Observable.add` when working with events). Currying is another good point (I use `iter` when occasionaly too when I can use currying). However, I've also seen code that uses `iter` to make code look more "functional" with the only result that it looks less readable... I think that one has to be more careful about readability in F# (because it is perhaps (?) easier to write code that looks scary)

Comment: @Pavel, @Tomas - Of course it is all just a matter of opinion. In the case of the `for` loop it really lets the reader know that something with side effects is going on. When I see `iter` being used I can help but think an sequence of side-effect free function calls.

Answer (score 5):

```
resultSet |> Map.iter (fun key value ->
   printf "Key = %A, Value = %A\n" key value)
```

Comment: Curious - any reason for printf with a \n at the end of the string rather than just printfn?

Comment: I ask the opposite question whenever I see `printfn`. No reason, of course, just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

(This is a shorter answer than Tomas' one, going to the point.) Dictionaries are mutable, in F# it's more natural to use Maps (immutable). So if you're dealing with `map: Map<K,V>`, iterate through it this way:

```
for KeyValue(key,value) in map do
    DoStuff key value
```