# Recursive C# function returns from inside a for-loop - how to translate to F#?

Tags: c#, loops, f#, return, c#-to-f#

Long time C# developer, learning F#.  I picked a fairly functional-styled bit of C# code that I'd written as a learning exercise - translate it to F#.  I've done a lot of reading about functional programming and use the functional constructs in C# regularly, but I'm only a few hours into learning F#.

This function is part of a program that solves a puzzle similar to "LonPos 101" which you can find on Amazon, etc. The strategy used in the solver was based on recognizing that there are only 30 valid positions in the puzzle space, so a "solution so far" could be represented by a single integer, and every valid position of each piece could also be represented by a single integer and that a complete solution is a set containing one possible position from each of the 7 pieces where the "weights" of the 7 pieces add up to the solution weight (2^30-1).  In the given function, "key" is the "primary key" of the piece, wbk is "weights by key" - indexed by key, containing a list of valid positions for the corresponding piece, while "w" is the aforementioned "solution-so-far".  The return value is a map from key to chosen position and is filled-in on the exit path from a successful recursion that resulted in a solution.  I found when developing the C# solution that making this a sorted list made the solution finder an order of magnitude faster, but it's equally valid with an ordinary list.

Here's the C# function I'm having trouble with:

```
int solutionWeight;

Dictionary<int,int> Evaluate(int w, Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>> wbk, int key)
{
  if (w == solutionWeight)
    return new Dictionary<int, int>();  

  if (key == 8)
    return null;

  foreach (var w2 in wbk[key])
  {
    if ((w & w2) != 0)
      continue;
    var s = Evaluate(w | w2, wbk, key + 1);
    if (s != null)
    {
      s.Add(key, w2);
      return s;
    }
  }

  return null;
}
```

Here's my attempt at an F# version - it compiles, but it doesn't work correctly - it ends up failing with a KeyNotFoundException in the let ss=... line when executing the case where w is not solutionWeight and key does equal 8.  It makes no sense to me why this line of code is even being executed in this case, but...

```
    let rec Evaluate(w:int, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key:int):Dictionary<int,int> =
    if w = solutionWeight then 
        Dictionary<int,int>()
    else if key = 8 then 
        null
    else
        // ... this is wrong - runs off the end of some collection - fails with key not found exception
        let ws = wbk.[key] |> Seq.filter (fun w2 -> (w2 &&& w) = 0) 
        /// ... for some reason, execution resumes here after the key = 8 clause above
        let ss = ws |> Seq.map (fun w -> (w,Evaluate(w, wbk, key+1))) 
        let sw = ss |> Seq.find (fun sw -> snd sw <> null) 
        let s = snd sw 
        s.Add(key, fst sw)
        s
```

Point me in the right direction!  My next attempt will be to re-write the C# code in a more functional style first, but it feels like this version is on the verge of working (while perhaps still far from idiomatic F#).

UPDATE:

I re-wrote the F# function to eliminate the loop by using a pair of mutually recursive functions.  It does work, but it's ~2X slower than the non-mutually-recursive C# version.

```
let rec Evaluate(w:int, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key:int):Dictionary<int,int> =
    if w = solutionWeight then 
        Dictionary<int,int>()
    else if key = 8 then 
        null
    else
        EvalHelper(w, wbk, key, wbk.[key].GetEnumerator())

and EvalHelper(w:int, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key:int, ws:IEnumerator<int>):Dictionary<int,int> =
    if ws.MoveNext() then
        let w2 = ws.Current
        if (w &&& w2) = 0 then
            let s = Evaluate(w ||| w2, wbk, key+ 1)
            if s <> null then
                s.Add(key, w2)
                s
            else
                EvalHelper(w, wbk, key, ws)
        else
            EvalHelper(w, wbk, key, ws)
    else
        null
```

How can I further improve it?

UPDATE: I tweaked it more - feeling a bit more F#ish, but I still feel like I should be able to get rid of more type annotations and use F# native types more.  It's a work in progress.

```
let rec Evaluate(w, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key):Dictionary<int,int> option =
    let rec EvalHelper(ws) =
        match ws with
        | w2 :: mws ->
            match w &&& w2 with
            | 0 ->
                let s = Evaluate(w ||| w2, wbk, key+ 1)
                match s with
                | None -> EvalHelper(mws)
                | Some s ->
                    s.Add(key, w2)
                    Some(s)
            | _ -> EvalHelper(mws)
        | _ ->
            None

    if w = solutionWeight then 
        Some (Dictionary<int,int>())
    else if key = 8 then 
        None
    else
        EvalHelper(List.ofSeq wbk.[key])
```

Comment: With functional coding you should think about the simplest expressions first then compose them into more complicated expressions until you have what you need. In other words look from the bottom up not the top down. Break your function up into smaller and smaller parts and make sure they work, then combine them.

Comment: That's definitely my next tactic - this program overall makes a lot of use of immutable data structures and functional constructs - but this particular function - not so much.

Comment: `How can I further improve it?` Take a look at [Option Type](http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/) instead of using `null`. Use [for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3267704/1243762) instead of `MoveNext`. Use [match](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/match-expression/) instead of using nested `if then`. Use [guards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/match-expressions) with `match`. Use [nested function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nested_function) instead of `let rec ... and ...` if possible.

Comment: I'll keep those in mind, thanks!  Time to find a new project for F# - this one's in the can.

Comment: If you like your own answer then post it as an answer. People tend to skip looking at questions if they don't see an answer. Do yourself a favor and get some extra points, especially to 50 so you can [comment everywhere](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). You can always edit your answer after you post it.

Comment: Thanks again.  I've been a developer for nearly 40 years but an SO user for just a few days - still learning the ropes!

Comment: Interesting to see the progress you made in such short time, gays off! Perhaps you could update your question with what the function is supposed to do abs give a few sample input/output test cases perhaps? It'll help understand the question and perhaps improving on the answer.

Comment: @Abel Good idea - I added some background info. Since this is a puzzle solver, the sample input is the puzzle and the output is the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to translating this function was to turn the for loop into recursion, as shown in the first update.

```
let rec Evaluate(w:int, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key:int):Dictionary<int,int> =
    if w = solutionWeight then 
        Dictionary<int,int>()
    else if key = 8 then 
        null
    else
        EvalHelper(w, wbk, key, wbk.[key].GetEnumerator())

and EvalHelper(w:int, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key:int, ws:IEnumerator<int>):Dictionary<int,int> =
    if ws.MoveNext() then
        let w2 = ws.Current
        if (w &&& w2) = 0 then
            let s = Evaluate(w ||| w2, wbk, key+ 1)
            if s <> null then
                s.Add(key, w2)
                s
            else
                EvalHelper(w, wbk, key, ws)
        else
            EvalHelper(w, wbk, key, ws)
    else
        null
```

The subsequent update just cleaned up the style a bit - pushed it a little closer to idiomatic F#.

```
let rec Evaluate(w, wbk:Dictionary<int, SortedSet<int>>, key):Dictionary<int,int> option =
    let rec EvalHelper(ws) =
        match ws with
        | w2 :: mws ->
            match w &&& w2 with
            | 0 ->
                let s = Evaluate(w ||| w2, wbk, key+ 1)
                match s with
                | None -> EvalHelper(mws)
                | Some s ->
                    s.Add(key, w2)
                    Some(s)
            | _ -> EvalHelper(mws)
        | _ ->
            None

    if w = solutionWeight then 
        Some (Dictionary<int,int>())
    else if key = 8 then 
        None
    else
        EvalHelper(List.ofSeq wbk.[key])
```

Comment: You have me by 4 years. I did work with punch cards but not paper tape. Did you use paper tape and/or toggle switches? Also an answer should be self contained in case a link/reference is broken. While your answer is obviously in the question, programmers are the laziest people I know, but that is a good thing.

Comment: I did punch cards (Fortran 67 - yea!) but no paper tape.  Worked on many systems that supported tape, but never had to go that route.  Good times.  Thanks for the tips - no worries about editing my answer.  You're absolutely right about programmers being the laziest people I know!

Comment: @GuyCoder Oh, the irony of it all.  Looking at the compiled assembly with a .NET decompiler (to C#) I can see that the compiler actually took my recursive EvalHelper function and turned it back into a loop in the generated code.  Looking at the generated IL, it's not surprising that the F# version of this program is roughly 1.5X slower than the C# version - impressive that it's not worse than that.

Comment: When I write functional code my first thought is not about how fast it is, but about how accurate it is. Are you aware of [algebraic data types](http://chris-taylor.github.io/blog/2013/02/10/the-algebra-of-algebraic-data-types/) yet?

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of algebraic data types, at least a bit.  Interesting series you linked there - I got partway through it, will get back to finish it in the new year :)  I try (very hard!!) to avoid premature optimization - but being a crusty old developer that started on machines with <1K of memory, it's hard to not always think about runtime cost - it's in my DNA at this point!

Comment: What's old is new. If you hang out in Neural Networks or Deep Learning then runtime cost is one of the big factors if not the biggest. When problems take up to months to solve, every little bit helps. I personally self-taught myself enough to understand it, but now am waiting/working towards getting [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/) to run on Windows either natively or via [WSL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/faq).